# Live preview of textarea input with javascript html

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, auto-update

Hi I am setting up a live preview of the input of a textarea which will be posted to a blog. I currently have this set up

```
<textarea name="WPcomment" id="WPComment" placeholder="Add comments:" onkeypress="document.getElementById('prevCom').innerHTML = this.value"></textarea>

<div id="prevCom"></div>
```

The issue is that the preview is one character behind the input of the textarea. For instance if i write "my comment" I see "my commen"

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use keyup and keypress events, keyup alone won't work if someone holds down a key and it repeats.

```
var wpcomment = document.getElementById('WPComment');

wpcomment.onkeyup = wpcomment.onkeypress = function(){
    document.getElementById('prevCom').innerHTML = this.value;
}​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RZwmX/1)

Comment: @Musa How can anybody make this work using div in stead of textarea? I have a code that I do not want to alter using a textarea. I want it to load in the live preview box. Then, as a second step I will have something like this where the user will be able to alter specific parts : http://apolosiskos.co.uk/HTML-CSS-EDITOR/index3.html

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `onkeypress="..."`

Change to `onkeyup`. This will fix the issue your having with the with the characters not updating as expected.

So your final code should be:

```
<textarea name="WPcomment" id="WPComment" placeholder="Add comments:" onkeyup="document.getElementById('prevCom').innerHTML = this.value"></textarea>
<div id="prevCom"></div>​
```

[Check out this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VkpjP/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<textarea name="WPcomment" id="WPComment" placeholder="Add comments:" onkeyup="document.getElementById('prevCom').innerHTML = this.value"></textarea>

<div id="prevCom"></div>​
```

Use `onkeyup` instead of `onkeypress`

here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/urw88/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change with `onkeyup or onchange`

```
onkeyup ="document.getElementById('prevCom').innerHTML = this.value"
```

Answer (score 0):

`onkeyup` event in javascript  will take the letter as soon you press it